# downloading from blob works locally but not after publishing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, download, cloud, azure-blob-storage

Im creating a website which can b used to upload files to cloud and downloading the same. When i try to download the file when it is running locally everything works fine. After publishing the file to Azure the status shows that the file is downloaded but the file is not available in the download location.
Thanks in Advance

```
//My Download Code
` protected void OnDownloadImage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
  {
     var account = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DataConnectionString");
     var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
     CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = client.GetContainerReference("Gallery");
     var blobUri = (string)e.CommandArgument;
     var srcBlob = this.GetContainer().GetBlobReference(blobUri);
     srcBlob.FetchAttributes(new BlobRequestOptions { BlobListingDetails = BlobListingDetails.Metadata });
     var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory));
     path = path + @"\AJStorage";
     Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
     path = path + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(srcBlob.Metadata["FileName"]);
     srcBlob.DownloadToFile(path);
     this.status.Text = "File Download Successful. File Location : " + path;
   }`
```

Comment: @Jothishwar RS, please reformat your code in your question and explain a little more to get help.

Comment: i think the problem is with my setting up of the path to save the file to the local disc. The error might be because the server is not having proper permission for creating the file. I want to know how to alter my code in order to allow the downloading of file from server while it works fine locally.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the issue. You are trying to download the file to the desktop - but that will be the desktop of the web server (where you will almost certainly not have permission) and not the desktop of the user (which is probably what you were after). If it is, you can't do that directly. Instead try sending the file to the HTTP Response stream. (I use DownloadToStream which is part of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient)

Comment: thnx Andiih for you response. exactly wat u said is the error in my website. Now i cleared my error and is all set to wrk :)
thnx a lot

i ve reffered the following blog too.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/05/downloading-word-and-excel-files-from-windows-azure-storage-in-a-asp-net-web-role.aspx

Comment: Cool - that code you reference uses DownloadToStream and is almost exactly what I do :-)